# Is equality check required before raising PropertyChanged?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Is is necessary to check for a property value changed before calling `RaisePropertyChanged` or does it already know if it really needs to raise it ? See below.

```
public string Reason
{
    get { return pReason; }
    set
    {
        //Is this if statement needed or beneficial?
        if (pReason != value)
        {
            pReason = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Reason");
        }
    }
}
string pReason = string.Empty;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are binding dependency property to your property it practically does not matter.

However, if you are raising the `PropertyChanged` event even when the property has not changed, you are lying to the consumer. in this case it does not matter, but in another cases it can matter.

I recommend you to create your own code snippet in Visual Studio for properties that calls PropertyChanged event.

if you put breakpoint to the getter, you will see that somebody (wpf binding) is trying to get the value even when it has not changed

Answer (score 0):

Raising the event when the value hasn't changed might not only be a lie to the objects that listen for the event but could significantly affect performance.

In general a View will be bound to the property of the ViewModel. It is quite likely that the view in response to the event recalculates its layout, redraws its controls, and raises its own events. This way a single, apparently harmless, lie could escalate to a unnecessary redraw of a large part of the UI. If the View is a cell in a grid it could trigger the redraw of the grid, resorting, refiltering, etc.

Comment: It could even result in an infinite loop, where a PropertyA updates PropertyB, which updates PropertyA again, all without values actually changing, and so on. Properly checking if the value hasn't changed can prevent this.